Android Compose - Type safe Navigation: Serializer for class 'MainScreen' is not found
I am trying to use Android Compose Type Safe navigation but I got this error.
How do i solve it?
The objects:
@Serializable
data object MainScreen {

    @Serializable
    data class MainScreenFirstScreen(val id: Int? = null)
}

I have to navigate to the MainScreen passing in id from another screen
FirstLoginOwnerSixthScreenRoot(
    onNavigateToNextScreen = { id ->
        navHostController.navigate(
            route = MainScreen.MainScreenFirstScreen(
                id = id
            )
        ) 

The Graph:
fun NavGraphBuilder.mainScreenOwnerNavGraph() {
    navigation<MainScreen>(
        startDestination = MainScreen.MainScreenFirstScreen()
    ) {
        composable<MainScreen.MainScreenFirstScreen> { navBackStackEntry ->
            val navHostController = LocalNavHostContoller.current

            Text("Main Screen")
        }
    }
}

But I got the following error:
kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'MainScreen' is not found.
                                                                                                    Please ensure that class is marked as '@Serializable' and that the serialization compiler plugin is applied.

I do similar things elswhere in the app and nowhere else is a problem

This question is similar to: Serializer for class '...' is not found. Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
